# Timing out blocked HTTP resources more quickly

Tags: browser, tcp, hosts

I block several popular ad targeting domains in my /etc/hosts file. For example:

```
127.0.0.1 ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 a.adroll.net
```

However, sometimes sites put blocking calls to these servers in the `<head>` of their web documents, and Chrome won't draw the rest of the page until the request times out, which can take a while.

Is there a way I can speed up the process of timing out these requests?

Comment: Block them how? Do you have the option of blocking them such that an RST is issued instead of no response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting the requests to 127.0.0.1 via hosts ofcourse implicates a request to localhost. If you have a webserver running there, you catch all these requests, which might incur some processing time.

If you have no server running on localhost and a firewall, that drops requests to port 80, things might become even uglier: It can take quite a while for client/os-combo to give up, if packets are silently dropped.

So, try the following:

- If you have a webserver on localhost, make sure it answers with a 404 fast
- If you have no local webserver but a firewall, add a rule to it **not** to drop packets coming from localhost - this will end up in a fast "connection denied"

Comment: Is there a known server besides localhost I can redirect to, that will do a fast connection denied?

Comment: You could use the net IP on your local LAN, e.g. 192.168.1.0 if your LAN is 192.168.1.x